# iPhone SE Can't be updated to iOS 15.6 without factory reset - any risk?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup

I have an iPhone SE running iOS 11, I wanted to update it to 15.6.
At first I made a backup using itunes because I knew something can go wrong.
I then tried installing 15.6 but got an error

```
the iphone iphone could not be updated. an unknown error occurred (1110)
```

and now it says

```
your iphone cannot be updated you must restore it to factory settings
```

What steps should I take? If I restore to factory, what iOS is it going to have? 15? 11? or the one that came with SE the first time (maybe 10?)

After doing so, should I first install iOS 15 and then do a restore from backup, or first restore from backup, then clean up some files to have space for iOS 15, and only then install it?

Comment: I can only guess, but I would imagine there's a fair amount of risk. It's very doubtful anyone ever tested compatibility or the data converters for such a long jump. Google says error 1110 is "out of storage" so you may be able to delete some apps/content to give it enough room & try again.